# Outlook api webhook validation error with node js

Tags: node.js, outlook-restapi

I'm facing a problem with the validation of the notification url when I want to register a subscription with the outlook API.

The options passed in the request are :

```js
var optionsSubscription = {
    url: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "authorization": "Bearer " + user.outlookCalAccessToken,
        "accept": "application/json",
        "ContentType": "application/json",
    },
    json: {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
        "Resource": "me/events",
        "NotificationURL": "https://xxx/callback",
        "ChangeType": "Created,Deleted,Updated"
    },
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

The response is the following :

> Notification URL `'https://xxx/callback?validationtoken=N2FhY2JhNmItYTc2MC00MGUwLThmOGItZWQ2N2Q5Nzg5Y2Y2'` verification failed `System.Net.WebException`:
>
> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>    at Microsoft.Exchange.OData.Model.Notifications.PushNotification.PushSubscriptionCallbackUrlValidationHelper.SendRequestAndVerifyResponse (Uri callbackUrl, PushSubscription pushSubscription).

When I request the notification url with Postman, it works and returns the validation token with a `200` status as expected.

The SSL certificate is generated with let's encrypt.

Comment: Have you ensured the self-signed cert is trusted on your machine?

Comment: I think that certificates generated by Let's Encrypt on the machine are trusted !

Comment: I'm always facing this issue. Can you help me to know if the problem is the certificate ?